# How to get Icon of Current Active Window in C Sharp?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, icons, active-window

As we can get the title of active window in c sharp using method ActiveWindowTitle(). Now I need to get The icon of above same window.
how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried [WM_GETICON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-geticon)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you find a foreground window

```
GetForegroundWindow(
```

you can find out its process ID

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId(
```

and for that process, the file path

```
process.MainModule;
```

then just use the function

```
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon (executablPath);
```

See for example: [this](https://gist.github.com/sparksbat/38d3a8c31f36d18cc497831631691067)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use  `this. icon`.

[image]